# Downloading a file from FTP using kettle

Tags: ftp, download, pentaho, kettle

I was trying to download a file form FTP server(Remote machine) using pentaho kettle (Get a file with FTP), I can able to do that in my local machine. But when i try to deploy the app in jboss web server it fails to download resulting in a error "Error getting files from FTP : Login incorrect."

But everything seems to be correct regarding the login details.

Did i have configure any where else in the server? Please help.

Comment: can you try downloading using "Get file with SFTP" ?

Answer (score 0):

There are several things you could check in this case:

1. Check that the security settings of the remote FTP server allows for the machine that runs the job to establish an FTP connection. If you have access to the server, try the following command to ensure that the server has access:

   ```
   telnet <your-remote-ftp-server-host> 21
   # Or try:
   telnet <your-remote-ftp-server-host> 22
   ```
2. Verify that the remote FTP server respects FTP connection requests, otherwise try SFTP (*Get a file with FTP* & *Get a file with SFTP* are two entirely different job steps in Kettle)
3. Wherever you are fetching your FTP credentials from (ideally a configuration file), test that the credentials are properly read by the job in the relevant scope - use the **Write To Log** step for that matter